# Ad not from this site

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am having a problem when I am browsing the web on Ubuntu 13.10.

Whenever I browse, I start seeing ads with it saying ads not from this site!!!

Search on Google and it will say it's adware!

How do I get rid of it?

My browser is Google Chrome 30.0.1599.114 (Official Build 229842).

Comment: Try with Firefox to see if problem will remain.

Comment: Like others said, try Firefox. Seem running fine on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that Chrome/ium security measures to prevent attacks. I would disable all extensions (that could be replacing the advertisements causing what you see now) and see if it still happens. If doesn't happen, enable one by one all the extensions until you find the culprit and remove it.

AFAIK, those are not advertisements by YouTube or Google Adwords. I would also check if you are using a proxy of sorts that could also replace the ads you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the culprit and just found lately that there is a 'disable ads' option, so I turned that off. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you perhaps post which program was the culprit?

Comment: @rmahmud28 please, could you say which extension was the culprit or a list of your extensions?

Comment: @Minos Sure the Chrome app is called World Clocks [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pjgoijhajhaahklokegbfnohialajpej?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Comment: @Joe this is not the problem.